# How to merge two or more dotnet test code coverage files

Tags: .net, .net-core, code-coverage, dotnet-test

I have a .Net solution with two dotnet core class libraries and its associated unit test projects in it.

When I run `dotnet test **\*.Tests.csproj --collect "Code Coverage"` command then it generates separate .coveragexml files for each unit test project.

My requirement is to merge all the .coveragexml files into one single file and use that to get the total coverage matrix for a whole solution.

Is there any tool or script to achieve this?

**Note:**

- I am not using Coverlet.
- I am using built-in vstest.console.exe to run tests and generate .coveragexml file.
- I am using [Customize code coverage analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 2):

There is a dotnet tool called **[dotnet-coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-coverage)** that does this.

Install in on the machine (or your build server, if this is for your pipeline):

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-coverage
```

Generate your coverage with your preferred tools, and then you can use `dotnet-coverage` to merge them all into a single file.

**dotnet test files (.coverage):**

```
dotnet-coverage merge *.coverage --recursive --output merged.coverage
```

**dotnet test XML coverage files (.xml)**:

```
dotnet coverage merge *.xml --recursive --output coverage.xml --output-format xml
```

**Coverlet (.cobertura.xml)**:

```
dotnet-coverage merge *.cobertura.xml --recursive --output merged.cobertura.xml --output-format cobertura
```

#### Using in pipeline

To use it in an Azure DevOps pipeline, set up your step like this (this is for Coverlet, but can easily be adjusted):

```yaml
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: coverage
    arguments: 'merge *.coverage.xml --recursive --output MergedCoverage.cobertura.xml --output-format xml'
```

And then publish the merged coverage report:

```yaml
steps:
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage from MergedCoverage.cobertura.xml'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: MergedCoverage.cobertura.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is not necessary that the outcome of the merge is still in .coveragexml format you could use the [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) as a merging tool.

It's an open source tool on GitHub and takes several inputformats (and files) and has the option to convert it into several other formats. I'm afraid .coveragexml isn't one of the output formats, but it is one of the input formats.

Here is an example to run in the command line:

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"dotnet.exe" -targetArgs:"test {solution.sln}" -output:"{outputDir}\OpenCover.xml" {-oldstyle}
```

More details on the commands can be found in the [ReportGenerator docs](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator).

Comment: Stackoverflow best practice is to include examples with links since external links eventually die.

Comment: @Urasquirrel this is a link to an open-source tool.. so yeah.. can you explain to me what I should do? :D

Comment: No problem mate! Apologies, I wasn't clear. Stackoverflow best practice is to include an example as code in the tic marks like ``` put example here ```. You can just copy the code from the site and put it here so if the link dies, we still have the example.

Comment: @Urasquirrel yeah i know what you mean, but the problem is the code is useless if the link dies, cause you need to tool for it (link) :D But if you think it's necessary I'll put some code into the answer.

Comment: @h)p3zZ yes you got it. StackOverflow trains us to do it this way as a best practice. It also encourages us to teach others. (/thumbsup)

Comment: @Urasquirreli added a "code" example